# How do I dynamically assign s3bucket and s3key values in code parameter from the input artefact using parameteroverride?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

This is my perfectly working cloudformatoin yaml template, how do I add paramteroverride code in this to obtain the values for s3bucket and s3key. This is triggered by changes to the codecommit repo and uses codepipeline.

```
Resources: 
  LFVQS2: 
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function' 
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: "liveranks1" 
      Handler: 'index.liveranks1' 
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::561731601292:role/service-role/mailfwd-role-m5rl5tu3' 
      Code:
        S3Bucket: 'codepipeline-us-east-1-13376757575759078361'
        S3Key: 'BackEnd/SourceArti/RZZUcIg'
      Runtime: "nodejs8.10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Fn::GetArtifactAtt

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html